# D3 line chart clipped y axis

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to build a chart in d3 and it works easily in the fiddle. However, when I put the code into my actual implementation the resulting svg element is cut of on the top and on the left. I played around with size and margins but somehow, nothing changes.

Here is the fiddle with the working code and the pasted svg as my actual implementation provides: http://jsfiddle.net/16jjdyt1/5/

An here is a picture of the output I am getting:
[image]
And here is the code from my actual implementation.

```js
 function updateGraph(data) {
  var selector = "#" + id + " .chart svg";

  // NOTE this is a hack, sometimes chart is null!
  if (!_.isEmpty(data.primary)) {

    d3.selectAll(selector + " > *").remove();


    var width = 400,
      height = 140;
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 30, left: 50}

    var parseDate = d3.time.format('%d.%m.%y %H:%M').parse;
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y0 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);


    // ticks
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").tickFormat(function(d) {
          return d3.time.format('%d.%m.%y %H:%M')(new Date(d))
        })
        .ticks(5); // TODO change this

    var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y0)
        .orient("left").tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

    var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1)
        .orient("right").tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

    // function for left aligned lines
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .y(function(d) { return y0(d.y); })
        .interpolate("cardinal").tension(0.8);

    // function for right aligned lines
    var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .y(function(d) { return y1(d.y); })
        .interpolate("cardinal").tension(0.8);

d3.select(selector)
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + 20)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom +20)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    // TODO refactor this
  var x_values = [];
  var y0_values = [];
  var y1_values = [];



  _.each(data.primary, function(d){
      _.each(d.values, function(f){
          x_values.push(f.x);
          y0_values.push(f.y);
      });
  });   // TODO refactor this!

  _.each(data.secondary, function(d){
      _.each(d.values, function(f){
          x_values.push(f.x);
          y1_values.push(f.y);
      });
  });   // TODO refactor this!

  x.domain(d3.extent(x_values)); // scale  x axis
  y0.domain(d3.extent(y0_values)); // scale  y axis 1
  y1.domain(d3.extent(y1_values)); // scale y axis 2


  // Add left aligned graphs
  data.primary.forEach(function(d){
    d3.select(selector).append("path")
      .style("stroke", d.color) 
      .attr("d",valueline(d.values));
  });

  // Add right aligned graphs
  data.secondary.forEach(function(d){
    d3.select(selector).append("path")
      .style("stroke", d.color)
      .attr("d",valueline2(d.values));
  });



  d3.select(selector).append("g")            // Add the X Axis
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);


  d3.select(selector).append("g") // Add first y axis
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxisLeft);

  d3.select(selector).append("g") // Add second y axis
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")
      .call(yAxisRight);


  }
}

return timechart;
  };
```

I have no idea where this error might lay so I am happy for any hints with this. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you putting the code in your final implementation? I just tried grabbing the output svg and it seems to work fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/16jjdyt1/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths, axis etc should be sitting inside the `g`element, like this::

```
<g transform="translate(50,30)">
    // in 'test', chart goes here
</g>
```

However, in you 'output' version, the chart elements are all after the `g`:

```
<g transform="translate(50,30)"></g>
// in 'output', chart goes here
```

In the code for you actual implementation, you first append that `g` to the `selector` (which is the svg element) ...

```
d3.select(selector)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + 20)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom +20)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

And then you append other bits, which will go *after*, rather than being *nested inside*, the translated `g`, like this:

```
d3.select(selector).append("g")            // Add the X Axis
  .attr("class", "x axis")
```

To avoid this, one thing you could do is define an `id` for the `g`, and select that to use to add your axis and paths to, eg:

```
d3.select(selector)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + 20)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom +20)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("id", "selector_g";
```

and then

```
d3.select("#selector_g").append("g")            // Add the X Axis
  .attr("class", "x axis")
```